# Jquery Divide and then Append to multiple divs

Tags: jquery, append, divide

I have a page with differentiating amounts of colums determined by user selection.

Upon changing, for arguments sake, from three to two colums I want to take all content (child divs) from all three colums and then re distribute them evenly(ish) between the now remaining two colums.

This is what I have so far.

```
// gather contents from source colums and store, store target divs as well
   var source = jQuery(".col").contents();
   var target = jQuery("#cols").contents();

// clear target divs (individually) now that their content is stored so we can append and re distribute source content
   jQuery(".col").html('');

// insert source into target
   jQuery(target).append(source);
```

#cols is a container containing all visible colums and .col is each of these individual colums. So I am successfully saving the content from each individual colum (.col) and appending it to the colum container (#col) where it is then placing the content into each child of this container (each colum or .col).

So it is working fine but it is of course DUPLICATING the entire lot of content in each colum where I actually want to DIVIDE it between each colum evenly.

I hope this makes sense... any ideas?

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/Cgdyq/ click screen options to change colum settings and you will notice the content multiplying depending on colum number of colums selected.

Comment: A concrete example as http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be very helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cgdyq/

Click "Screen Options" then change the number of colums and you will see the content multiplies.

Comment: `jQuery("#cols").contents();` will return all child nodes and append each node in `source` to each of them. If you want to divide it, you have to iterate over the nodes in `target` and add the corresponding nodes from `source`.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I had a feeling I had to do something such as this just not sure the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by dividing the source by the number of colums and splitting the array before placing each resulting chunk in each colum and the reaminder colum (if it exists) into the last colum.